# How does Javascript implements variable bindings?

Tags: javascript, variables, binding, resolution

How does javascript interpreter bind a memory location to the reference?

Does it create a table where it stores definitions with corresponding randomly chosen memory locations and then just looks up the table when it needs to resolve an identifier?

Something similar to this?

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  id  | definition | scope_id | location_x | location_y |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 523  |     foo    |    31    |  00101010  |  00100110  |
| 613  |     bar    |    32    |  00100110  |  01000100  |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

It would be cool to know exactly how variable binding and resolution works.

Comment: The assumption is that each browser has it's own implementation of the javascript specification(s).  So there is presumably not one single way that this is done.

Comment: What are `location_x` and `location_y` supposed to represent? A variable binding only needs one location.

Comment: @Barmar memory cells are arranged in a two dimensional grid

Comment: Memory is just linear addresses, unless you're talking about segmented memory (and even then, you can just think of the segment number as the high order bits in a single address).

Comment: @Barmar to activate any memory latch, corresponding row and column wires has to be turned on hence x for column and y for row

Comment: That's at the hardware level, we don't deal with that when programming. In software, addresses are just a single number.

Comment: @Barmar well that single address has x and y components

Comment: Software doesn't treat it like that. Every programming language that has pointers treats it as a single number.

Comment: Most JS implementations are probably C or C++. Where would the x and y components appear in that code?

Comment: take an address for instance 0x80 
0x80  is 10000000 in binary
first 4 bits are for column and last for row

so 1000 indicates a column and 0000  a row

Comment: If you're storing a 2-dimensional array in memory that's what you would do. But there's no reason why a JS variable binding environment would need to treat it as a 2-dimensional array.  The rows don't represent anything meaningful in the software, so it will just be a 1-dimensional array.